# Grape Gem encoding in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, ruby-grape, grape-api

In the API response, there are HTML entities. Please can you make it return decoded entities.

```
{"success_message":"Record found","result":[{"category":"Health \u0026 Safety"}]}
```

SHOULD BE

```
{"success_message":"Record found","result":[{"category":"Health & Safety"}]}
```

I am using grape gem for api and I also try this

# default_format :json

```
format :json
content_type :json, "application/json;charset=iso-8859-1"
```

In my api but still now working.

Comment: `\u0026` has nothing to do with HTML entities.

Comment: In my database this is stored like "Health & Safety"

Comment: In response after json encode this looks like this

Comment: It’s a perfectly valid ruby string. Try in `irb`: `p "Health \u0026 Safety" #⇒ "Health & Safety"`. I don’t get what’s your problem.

Comment: i think Problem with grape gem that send json in response

Comment: There is no problem at all. What you get and what you expect to get are the same strings. You might try `content_type :json, "application/json;charset=utf-8"` if you want to see explicit ampersand in the response.